# Lim sup of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I guess it is a simple question...
Let $a$ and $c$ be real numbers.

If $\lim_{x\to \infty} M(x)=a$, does the following then hold?
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{x}M(s)s^c\,\mathrm ds=a\limsup_{x\to\infty}\int_{1}^{x}s^c\,\mathrm ds$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $c = -2$ and set $M(x) = 1/x$. Then $a = 0$ but
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} M(s)s^{-2} \, \mathrm ds = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s^3} \, \mathrm ds = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0 . $$

Comment: Ok! So,  if $a\neq 0$ the statement is true, isn't it?

Comment: No, consider $c=-2$, $M(s)=1+e^{-s}$